# How to estimate Realm DB size

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is there any good way how to estimate Realm file size on iOS and what is the highest safe Realm DB size? I am doing an app that gathers time series data and I am now elaborating which granularity to choose.

Let's say that I would like to keep following amount: Set of 15 doubles, saved each 5 seconds for 2 hours in a day, kept for 10 years.

This makes approx 15x(60/5)x60x2x365x10 = 78 mil. of double entries. I suppose this amount is too big to be stored in iPhone thus I should always keep data let's for 1 year max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check the math

You said

> Set of 15 doubles, saved each 5 seconds for 2 hours in a day, kept for
>   10 years.

here's that in numbers

```
8 Bytes in a double * 15 doubles * 1440 samples per day (see below) * 3650 Days
```

= 630720000 Bytes

Now take 630720000 Bytes * 0.00000095367432 = 601Mb (in Binary) or 640Mb in Decimal

That could easily be done in Realm and on a phone. 650Mb is a lot less than a 64Gb phone can hold.

I am sure there is more overhead involved so the numbers may vary but it seems possible unless I missed something.

Samples Per Day = Two hours is 7200 seconds / 5 = 1440